# Me/my not knowing the truth?

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds, possessives

A gerund is a verbal, and always functions as a noun. It is formed by adding "ing" to the verb.
I have recently found out that gerund must be modified by a possessive noun or pronoun. However, it is important to distinguish between a present participle and a gerund, something I sometimes have trouble with.

The noun or pronoun before the gerund is called the subject of the gerund, and should be in the possessive form. However, what if there is a word of negation (no or not) positioned in between? Below are the two examples I thought of. I believe that both of them are gerunds and not participles.
Which is the correct construction according to the above grammar rule?

- She is  worried about me not knowing the truth

or

- She is worried  about my not knowing the truth

Now, I know I should be confident in using the second example, given the rule. However, I just want to make sure that there is no exception or changed even when there exists a word of negation separating the noun/pronoun and the gerund.

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable. The first is more common in speech while the second tends to be more formal or literary.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=about+me+not+knowing%2Cabout+my+not+knowing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=50), although "my" is more common than "me", both are used.  "Me" is more recent, but should be acceptable.

However, the use of "me" [seems exclusive to AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/interactive_chart?content=about%20me%20not%20knowing%2Cabout%20my%20not%20knowing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=50&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cabout%20my%20not%20knowing%3B%2Cc0).  A British speaker might insist that "my" is the only *correct* option.

Personally I also prefer "my" as it aligns better with "She was worried about".